# print out all the numbers between user input and condition that are divisible by 2 and 3. while loop ask for another number

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, loops

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter in value: " << endl;
    cout << "\/";
    cin >> x;

    while(x < 0) {
        cout << "value cannot be negative" << endl;
        cin >> x;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++)
    {
        if (y % 2 == 0 && y % 3 == 0) {
            cout << y << " " << endl;
        }
    }
    {int main();
    int x = 100;
    }
    { 
        char ans = 'N';
        do {
            cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N)?\n";
            cout << "You must type a 'Y' or an 'N' :";
            cin >> ans;
        } while ((ans == 'Y') || (ans == 'y'));
    }

    system("pause");
    return(0);  
}
```

my problem is that when i enter a number it will show the values that are divisible by 2 and 3, but when the "do you want to continue" part runs it just keeps asking do you want to continue instead of enter in another number.

Comment: `{ int main(); int x = 100; }` - Whatever you were hoping this would do, it doesn't. It declares a function (already known) and defines a variable that immediately goes out of scope. As such it's no more than a very elaborate no-op, if legal at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you were trying to do here or whether that's allowed,

```
{int main();
int x = 100;
}
```

but that may be due to my cpp knowledge.
Regardless, the way I do these sort of things is to surround the code you want to rerun in a while loop. Then after you have displayed the divisible numbers (inside the while loop), you can ask the user if they want to continue. If the user wants to continue, just do nothing and the while loop will run again. If the user wants to quit, break the while loop and possibly also terminate the program.

```
int main(){
    while(true) {
        // your code that needs to be repeated goes here
        int x;
        cout << "Enter in value: " << endl;
        cout << "\/";
        cin >> x;

        while(x < 0) {
            cout << "value cannot be negative" << endl;
            cin >> x;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++){
            if (y % 2 == 0 && y % 3 == 0) {
                cout << y << " " << endl;
            }
        }

        //ask the user to continue here
        cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N)?\n";
        cout << "You must type a 'Y' or an 'N' :";
        cin >> ans;
       
        //define the break condition for the loop
        if((ans != 'Y') || (ans != 'y')){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Because we set the while condition in the beginning to *true*, the loop will execute again until we manually stop it. To do that we use the break statement and have coupled that with the condition that the user did not enter either 'Y' or 'y'. But you can give it any condition you want to.
Now if the user gets prompted to enter a character, if he enters 'y', the program will advance to the next iteration of the while loop, restarting the division part of the code.

I hope that this is understandable and helpful and gives you a possible solution for your problem!